# Azure event grid with service bus topic subscription and Logic app web hook not triggering

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I am using Service Bus premium to create Event Subscription (Event Grid) and the Endpoint I am using Webhook ( Logic App Endpoint) .

My use case is : whenever the message is received in service bus topic the event should get trigger and the webhook should be called.

[image: Event Grid subscription]

[image: Event Type and Webhook endpoint]

The webhook endpoint is of Logic App URI .

Issue : For 15-20 message in the topic the event gets triggered and the logic app is fired and after that even for any number of message the event does not get triggers.

Note : I am using Peek-Lock in my logic app and the message is not completed yet , number of messages i can see in the topic/subscriptions which are not yet processed.

Event not triggering even there are many messages in the topic/subscription.

[image: My topic subscription/EventGrid subscription]

[image]

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept for details. Also, see my answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981438/eventgridtrigger-for-azure-service-bus-topic for cases, where the ASB entity emitted events to the AEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case, such as "*whenever the message is received in service bus topic the event should get trigger and the webhook should be called.*" can not be handled by Azure Event Grid.

The following use cases are in this scenario:

1. No event is published when there is no message in the entity.
2. The event is published immediately when the first message is arrived into the entity and there is no active listener for 360+ seconds on the entity
3. The event is published every 120 seconds when the listener is still non-active and there are at least one message in the entity
4. The event is published after 360 seconds listener idle (non-active) time and still there are at least one message in the entity. For example, if we have 5 messages in the entity and the subscriber will pull-up only one message using a REST Api, the next event will be published after 360 seconds. In other words, the *watchdog* entity allows to keep a listener in the idle time for 360 seconds.

As you can see, the AEG can help to wake up a receiver, in other words to avoid a continuously polling for messages in the ASB entity.